# MATE: Cannot see menu of QT applications (Skype, Virtualbox)

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, qt

I've just installed Mint Mate 17.3, fully upgraded, and I'm facing a strange issue: if I try to open the menu of QT applications (like Skype and Virtualbox) nothing happens, no menu popup appears.

[image: No menu]

This doesn't happen if I switch the window manager from Marco to Metacity.

Update: this seems to be a multi-monitor issue. I have a secondary **rotated** display, if I disable the rotation QT apps go back to normal.

Comment: Judging from the redhat bugzilla reports, this issue is related to specific bugs in the window managers, some have it (xfce does not have it, for example), some do, so the solution is to file bug reports with the relevant projects, Mate, Xmonad, and so on. I doubt spending time here on se will help in this case, but spending your time filing upstream bug reports would probably be very helpful, and let those projects correct the issues using any data they request from you. Not the most fun way to spend time, but it's how code gets improved.

Comment: Also note, Mint won't update to fix bug until next release, so the bug would probably never go away in Mint 17. Your case of xmonad really suggests that you should go to them and talk to them about the issue, I'm sure they would respond well. That was clear in the bugzilla report from redhat, a fix was issued by windowmaker and the issue was resolved.

Comment: could you please try to run virtualbox from your terminal ( launch the command from the terminal) and enable the rotated display... after that try to reproduce your error and see if the console shows some message, if it does, please let us know

Comment: @Lizardx I had already opened a (I think) related [issue](https://github.com/mate-desktop/marco/issues/319) with MATE months ago, I hope they'll find the time to have a look at it :)

Comment: @Lizardx I'm sorry, can you share the links to the bugzilla reports you're referring to?

Comment: For some reason, the post here was removed, that contained the redhat links, the xmonad comments, etc.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1182674 I wish that post had not been removed because it was highly relevant to your issue, in fact, it was in essence the answer, that is, the problem is with the specific window/display manager and qt. Note that bugzilla is about windowmaker and qt, the post was about xmonad and qt, and yours is about mate and qt. The total lack of response you got is not promising however. It could be that devs are refusing to deal with mint issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se, but a few comments on bugs and bug reporting.

First, you cannot report a bug on an out of date installation of the software, that's not really acceptable. So bugs that happen on old systems can't be in any real way dealt with because they could already have been fixed years ago.

This would refer to all frozen pool distributions, in particular Mint, Debian stables, Ubuntu LTR, Redhat enterprise, CentOS, and so on.

This puts users of such frozen pool distributions at a bit of a disadvantage when it comes to filing bug reports.

To help in this process, you have to do a few things:

1. Determine the current release of the software, Mate in this case.
2. Indicate which version your distribution is using, and the distribution version itself. It's not acceptable to assume that the developers of in this case Mate go and dig out this information on what version of Mate happened to be released with Mint 17.3, that's basically going to lead to them ignoring your issue, which is what happened.
3. Determine the current release of your distribution, and what version of Mate that uses.
4. Determine the versions of all related software: Nouveau, kernel, QT, Xorg.

It's entirely possible that there have been 100 or more releases of Mate between your version and the current git version, which is the only version they can really reliably do bug tracking on.

If you read your bug report to Mate/Marcos, you see that you are assuming that they either know or care what specifics of Mate are running in Mint. I can assure you as a developer this is NOT the case, when someone files an issue report, unless I can clearly determine it's totally unrelated to the version of my software they are using, on an old version, I basically close the issue and ignore it, since there's no possible way I can know what bugs I have fixed between years old software and today's.

You also failed to supply any system specs to them, via say inxi -bxxx for example.

Since your version of Mint, 17.3:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint_version_history

> Main  Cinnamon, MATE  4 December 2015 [made out of Ubuntu 14.4]

Was RELEASED almost 2 years ago, made out of release from Ubuntu that is almost 3 to 4 years old, but being released does not mean the packages it was made out of are 2-3 years old, it could well be that some are 3-4 years old, so you are in essence asking a Mate/Marcos maintainer to guess at what version of Mate was shipped at that time (which is why you must present them with the actual version of mate running on your system so they don't have to guess). Install the latest inxi, not the one that shipped with your legacy Mint (`sudo wget -O /usr/bin/inxi smxi.org/inxi` ) then it may show your Mate version, maybe.

AT this point, the developer may look at the report, but most likely they will close it for being on a Mate release that is far too old to even guess at the issues.

When you file this type of issue report, you put the maintainer in a very difficult position, because you're asking them to guess at something that is basically impossible to guess at, so my guess is, the way they handle that is to ignore it. I tend to respond to such issue reports with won't fix, won't look at it, and close it, since it's about out of date software.

Further, you're using a very old version of nouveau, with an old kernel, and an old Xorg, and an old QT, and the places issues could creep in between all these variables is totally impossible to guess at, but you have to as a bare minimum show the devs what software in fact you are talking about here. Likewise, you won't have a bit of luck posting an issue report to Mint, since there's no way they are going to be supporting the old release either, even if they claim they will. But that's where you should file your bug report, where it will sit unresolved 10 to 1.

There were QT issues reported that are similar for old windowmaker and old xmonad window managers, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1182674 is one, as you can see there, the issue was resolved in a newer release of windowmaker, which would almost by definition not enter that release of Redhat.

Comment: You're perfectly right, I should've added more details about my configuration :( I'll try to report the issue to the Mint developers, since 17.3 is a LTS release and thus still supported. I'll try to see if the problem is still present in the latest version of MATE, too. Many thanks for taking the time for this long answer!

Comment: Anyway, in partial defense of my bug report, I'd point out that I was asking how to help to debug the problem, not just a "please fix this bug" :D